# Getting size from view that places inside a ViewGroup with GONE visibility (programatically it will be set as VISIBLE)

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-bitmap

I'm trying to get a picture from my camera device, to save it, and show a preview in a `ImageView`.

My ImageView (named imagePreview) is defined inside the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/ll_selected_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone"> <!-- at first this is GONE -->
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/imagePreview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

When the image is acquired from the camera, I try to scale my image following [this document](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskScalePhoto), which code is:

```
private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

The problem is that I obtain a "division by zero" `mImageView.getWidth();` and `mImageView.getHeight();` return zero.

Note that the visibility of the parent `LinearLayout` is setted to `GONE`. Then, my application sets programmatically it to `VISIBLE`.

If I remove `GONE`, and I add `VISIBLE` instead, all works good!

The strange thing is that I have tried to add in the `setPic()`, as first code lines, the following code:

```
    if(ivSelectedImage.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        Log.i(TAG,"IS VISIBLE!");
    else if(ivSelectedImage.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
        Log.i(TAG,"IS GONE!");
    else if(ivSelectedImage.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
        Log.i(TAG,"IS INVISIBLE!");
```

and this prints in my console "IS VISIBLE"!

**BRIEFLY: If I set `GONE` in the XML, and then I set VISIBLE (programmatically) `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` can't get the correct value (also if when I call these methods the  View is actually VISIBLE).
While, If I set `VISIBLE` in the XML, the methods getHeight() and getWidth() return me the correct values.**

Comment: What if you set the visibility to `VISIBLE` in the XML (so the `getHeigth` and `getWidth` methods work), then set the visibility to `GONE` programatically at the beginning of your activity?

Comment: A view with visibility set to gone isn't included in the measuring and layout phase of the view hierarchy so there will not be any dimensions available for it. If you plan to show this view then invisible might be a better option instead of gone.

Comment: I have also tried as you said @G.T. , I have tried to set GONe visibility inside onCreate() method

Comment: @Luksprog I know it, but as I said I have tested inside my code the visibility of the View, and it always return "IS VISIBLE"

Comment: And have you get the size of the `View` before setting it to `GONE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the view size at runtime for this example. Based on your code, while the view visibility is set to gone the main container, your `LinearLayout`, as a fixed height of 300dp. As a result, you already know one of the dimensions of your view since at best android:layout_height="match_parent" can only be equal to 300dp.

To scale properly you just need the screen width - since your main view (and nested `RelativeLayout` and `ImageView` are also set to match_parent). If you're in an activity use this

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
```

otherwise you can get the display using

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Just run this calculation before you need the set the image. Store the results to `SharedPreferences` or something and then use that ratio the 300dp height and screen width to scale the image.

Comment: Thank you @Rare, it is a good idea, but I'd like to know why this happens: I dynamically change the visibility to VISIBLE, so it should work.

Comment: Do you change to visible before you get the measurements? Sound like what's happening is that the view isn't redrawing when you set the change programatically. Try calling invalidate() on the parent view - probably that outer `LinearLayout` which will make the system redraw.

Comment: calling invalidate() on the parent view, does not change the things. However you first solution is good! Thank you :)